# Relative Paths in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, relative-path

Relative paths in C# are acting screwy for me. In one case Im handling a set of Texture2d objects to my app, its taking the filename and using this to locate the files and load the textures into Image objects. I then load an image from a relative path stored in the class file and use a relative path that needs to be relative to Content/gfx. But if i dont load these textures these relative paths will fail. How can I garuantee that my rel path wont fail? In web work all rel paths are relative to the folder the file we're working from is in, can I set it up this way and make all rel paths to root folder where my app is located?

Comment: Is this in debug or in deployed mode?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recommend not using relative paths in the first place.

Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to turn your relative paths into absolute paths.  For example, you can use this to get the full path to your startup EXE:

```
string exeFile = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
```

Once you have that, you can get it's directory:

```
string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile);
```

and turn your relative path to an absolute path:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(exeDir, "..\\..\\Images\\Texture.dds");
```

This will be much more reliable than trying to use relative paths.

Comment: Thx alot for the two first lines, just was I was looking for. I would use '@' in the third line to avoid double backslashs though.

Comment: If my directory has a space in it, it can't find the path, but if it does not, it works fine.

Comment: why is it saved to the bin\Debug folder?

Answer (score 3):

If you are expecting a resource to be in the same directory as the executable file or in a sub directory of that directory, it's best to always use

```
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), subPath);
```

or if you are worried that the working directory might be wrong you can do this:

```
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), subPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

// [name space] is name space 
      //you should copy your file.-- into Depug file

```
      string path = (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + "");
      path = path.Replace("name space", "filename.--");


      // [WindowsFormsApplication4] is name space 
      //you should copy your "mysound.wav" into Depug file 

         //example::
       string path_sound  = (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + "");
      path_sound  = path_sound.Replace("WindowsFormsApplication4.exe", "mysound.wav");

      SoundPlayer player1 = new SoundPlayer(path_sound);
      player1.Play();
```