# How to set XamDataTree Icon to Bitmap instead of file name

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I've [set the XamDataTree image](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/xamDataTree_Expanded_and_Collapsed_xamDataTree_Nodes.html), but I don't want to copy the image folder to my debug folder every time. Instead I want to [add the image to my project resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521883/path-for-image-files-in-project) and use it from there. Currently no image is shown because it expects a path to an image where I give it an actual bitmap. The Icon property in the TreeNode is set in another part of the code.

This is my Xaml code:

```
<ig:XamDataTree
    Grid.Row="1"
    Name="MyTree" 
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ComparedContents}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    >
    <ig:XamDataTree.CheckBoxSettings>
        <ig:CheckBoxSettings CheckBoxVisibility="Visible" />
    </ig:XamDataTree.CheckBoxSettings>
    <ig:XamDataTree.CollapsedIconTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ig:XamDataTree.CollapsedIconTemplate>
    <ig:XamDataTree.ExpandedIconTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ig:XamDataTree.ExpandedIconTemplate>
    <ig:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
        <ig:NodeLayout
            Key="Children"
            DisplayMemberPath="Text"
            TargetTypeName="Model.TreeNode" 
            >
        </ig:NodeLayout>
    </ig:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
</ig:XamDataTree>
```

This is my model, each Property has a private store for the value and fires an event if it changes.

```
public class TreeNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Label Text;
    public System.Drawing.Image Icon;
    public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Children;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you embedded the image into your application, you can use a pack uri to load the image into the node template.  Instead of using an Image type on your Icon property you should use Uri and set it equal to something like this:

```
Icon = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/icon.png");
```

You need to modify the binding in your templates a bit because the DataContext of this template is going to be a XamDataTreeNodeDataContext.  This object has a Data property which will be your TreeNode object.  Your binding should be updated to:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Data.Icon}"/>
```