# How to display chm file in c# winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, chm

I have added .chm file to my application root. when i fetch the file using below code it is referencing the path to bin/release/somehting.chm

```
System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(this, Application.StartupPath+"\\"+"somehting.chm");
```

i want to get the path relative to installation location of application. please help.

the chm file added to the root directory is not loading after deploying the application. its not even loading while debugging in visual studio and not giving any error.

[image]

Comment: Is this the path it uses, while you are debugging inside Visual Studio or while the application is installed / deployed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)

Comment: Possible dublicate Relative [Paths in Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019641/relative-paths-in-winforms)

Comment: when i am running from visual studio its getting applicationfolder/bin/release/something.chm my something.chm file is under applicationfolder/something.chm. even when i deploy based on installed location i want the something.chm file path to be fetched

Comment: common mate why would i post question if it is duplicate. i will check the answers of previous similar questions and check if it was possible solution and if it is not then only i will post.

Comment: One thought, the reportmanager.hhp (project file of HTMLHelp Workshop or whatever application you are using) resides in your C# Project - this is not recommended. Please hold application development and help authoring in different places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see the first code snippet from your question calling `Help.ShowHelp` isn't so bad. Sometimes I'm using the related code below. Many solutions are possible ...
Please note, typos e.g. somehting.chm are disturbing in code snippets.

```
private const string sHTMLHelpFileName = "CHM-example.chm";
...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(this, Application.StartupPath + @"\" + sHTMLHelpFileName);
  }
```

So, please open Visual Studio - Solution Explorer and check the properties of your CHM file. Go to the dropdown box shown in the snapshot below and set "Always copy" (here only German). Start your project in `Debug` mode and check your bin/debug output folder. Do the same for `Release` mode and output folder. The CHM should reside there and I hope your CHM call works.

[image]

Comment: its working with debug and release modes, after following your instructions. but when i add the setup project and deploy the application. and run the application from setup file, its not working. can you please help

Comment: do i need to add the chm files to application folder of setup project

Comment: thanks mate, it was very helpful and solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You need :

```
String exeDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

So :

```
String HelpFilepath = "file://" + Path.Combine(exeDirectory , "somehting.chm");
Help.ShowHelp(this, path);
```

Comment: still going to bin/release folder

Comment: When you deploy the application, the results will be different. This returns the actual directory of the EXE you're running.

Comment: oh then its gonna be fine. ill deploy and test. thanks why windows development is like hell when compared to web

Comment: You can check the edited answer also, it is more guaranteed to get you the correct result.

Comment: its not working i have deployed my application and installed and checked its not showing. please help

Comment: Display the location "HelpFilepath" in a MessageBox, check if the chm is deployed with your application (Use File.Exists).
Maybe the location of your chm is changing after deployment. Check Directory.GetFiles(exeDirectory) results and display them in some way on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019641/relative-paths-in-winforms) is:

```
// get full path to your startup EXE
string exeFile = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;

// get directory of your EXE file
string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile);

// and open Help
System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(this, exeDir+"\\"+"somehting.chm");
```