# C# command line parameters taking relative path incorrectly

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, relative-path

I have an application which I want to run from command prompt.

I have opened command prompt.Below is the path

```
C:\Windows\system32>
```

Then i dragged my exe to the command prompt and after that below is the path

```
C:\Windows\system32>D:\Projects\xmlcreator\bin\Debug\xmlcreator.exe
```

when I click enter my xmlcreator.exe will run.When it is run I will read one of the config entry which is like this

```
<add key="location" value="..\..\DataFiles\RequiredFiles"/>
```

Above relative path should points to files in `D:\Projects\xmlcreator\DataFiles\RequiredFiles` that in the same solution folder.

But when I ran my exe it is pointing to the files in C:\DataFiles\RequiredFiles.

In command prompt if go to debug path and then execute exe path is identified correctly.That is

```
C:\Windows\system32>D:
D:\>cd D:\Projects\xmlcreator\DataFiles\RequiredFiles
D:\Projects\xmlcreator\DataFiles\RequiredFiles>xmlcreator.exe
```

If I run like above it identifies correctly the path of the xml i.e `D:\Projects\xmlcreator\DataFiles\RequiredFiles`.

so if I open command prompt and drag the exe to it and run then relative path is read incorrectly.I am not sure how can I handle this.

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1019684/2674937

Comment: Thanks @Esko. it worked.